# Effectively checking if a text file is entirely of spaces c++

Tags: c++

Is there a function or method to check if a text file consists of only white spaces or NULL ie '\0'. One method i used is to copy every line into string and check if that string only contains spaces or NULL. But that is not much effective as i have to copy every line into string.
Note. My test file contains lines of different lengths.

Comment: Each operating system has its own fastest (non-portable) way of reading a file. And file must be read, there's no other way. So, which OS is it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
bool hasCharacters(const char *file) {
    std::fstream fs(file);
    for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(fs), end; it != end; ++it)
        if (*it && !isspace(*it))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

This will return true if there's any character inside that's a non-space character.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit. I didn't got purpose of "const char *file"

Comment: You'd pass the file name as parameter. It's `const`, since you're not changing the contents of the passed strings.

Answer (score 1):

You just read the whole file one character at a time and check if each one is spaces or NUL. No need for any strings.

```
char ch;
while (file.get(ch))
{
    if (ch == ...)
    {
    }
}
```

There isn't a standard function to do this, but there is nothing to stop you writing your own function, or do you think your functions aren't as good as the standard ones somehow?

Comment: This will be more time consuming, i guess. Like if the text file is of 100mbs then 104857600 checks.

Comment: you cannot reduce this complexity, plus if you are checking line by line still you are checking 104857600 times, one per char

Comment: Compared to the time spent reading the file, the checking is unlikely to contribute meaningfully to the time the process takes to run.

Comment: @Hassie You do seem to have the delusion that the code you write is somehow inferior to the code written by others. To check a 1Mb file, you  have to check 1Mb characters, whether that's done in your code or in the standard library code makes no difference at all.